What is the meaning of なんと in this sentnece?
"なら、少し話すか"
"え?"
"そういって、なんと日向は恵子の椅子に座ってしまった。こを離れない、つまり本当に会話を続けるつもりなのだ"
I understand what the sentence mean, but why なんと here used? "Saying that, Hinata sat in Ayako's chair"

Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48316/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49075/9831
